# java.lang.ClassCastException while using PythonInterpreter from Java

Tags: java, python, pythoninterpreter

I am trying out to invoke python function passing it HashMap from within java (groovy). The python function squares every value in input map and returns Dictionary of squares with same keys.

**JythonTest.groovy**

```
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter
import org.python.core.*;

class JythonTest 
{
    static main(def args) 
    {
        PythonInterpreter pi;

        pi = new PythonInterpreter()
        pi.exec("from py1 import square3")
        PyFunction pf = (PyFunction)pi.get("square3")

        def map = ["value1":1,"value2":2,"value3":3]     //groovy map   
        PyDictionary pyDict = new PyDictionary(map)
        pf.__call__(pyDict)         //this is line 16 at which according to stack trace the exception is originated (as python function call occurs here)
    }
}
```

**py1.py**

```
def square3(map):
    squareMap = {}
    for k,v in map.items():        #this is line 3 where according to stack trace exception is occurring
        squareMap[k] = v*v
    return squareMap
```

But I am getting following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__pyclasspath__/py1.py", line 3, in square3
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.python.core.PyObject

    at org.python.core.PyDictionary.dict_items(PyDictionary.java:659)

    at org.python.core.PyDictionary$dict_items_exposer.__call__(Unknown Source)

    at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:449)

    at py1$py.square3$1(__pyclasspath__/py1.py:5)

    at py1$py.call_function(__pyclasspath__/py1.py)

    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:167)

    at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:138)

    at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:413)

    at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:408)

    at org.python.core.PyFunction$__call__.call(Unknown Source)

    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)

    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)

    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:122)

    at JythonTest.main(JythonTest.groovy:16)


java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.python.core.PyObject
```

In exception stack trace it says the exception is in python file line 3. But when I invoke the python function from python itself, say by attaching below line at the end of `py1.py`:

```
a = square3({"val1":1,"val2":2})
print(a)
```

I get following output:

```
{'val2': 4, 'val1': 1}
```

So why invoking python function from java fails? I am not getting whats going wrong here. Why call `pf.__call__(pyDict)` throwing such exception?

Comment: those line numbers help in locating code lines where stack trace says exception is occurred. Please think of undoing edit.

Comment: I'm sure people can count 3 lines and find the call to the python interpreter. Anyone copying the code would have to remove those line numbers in order to tests with it, which is annoying.

Comment: I understand your concern. Ok let me do some changes